# Extract particular words from Rsyslog %msg% facility

Tags: logs, rsyslog, filter

After lot of search on Google and reading all manuals available on man page and internet, I finally ask here.

In my scenario, I have one `rsyslog` server working with `mysql` and a custom template  written which take logs, filter them and write them to `mysql` database

My tmeplate is :

```
$template db_k,"insert into  
sensitive_logs(ID,TIME,message) 
values('%HOSTNAME%','%timegenerated:::date-mysql%','%msg%' )", sql
```

Output:

```
Security | 20140401182028  |  Failed password for root from 192.168.1.113 port 34290 ssh2
```

I'd like to extract some words from the %msg%

Example:

```
Failed,root,IP
```

from this message part

How can I do this?

Comment: it really depends what type of logs you get, if it's only for bad looging with ssh, you could use the word order to extract data, if you have several message, then there's no magic trick, you will have to parse each message depending of it's structure.

Comment: A little googling and this presents.. Any help?  http://www.rsyslog.com/regex/

Comment: @Kiwy This is just a sample, i have to configure this for large scale of different different types of log

Comment: rsyslog regexp seems to be the perfect match @SecurityBeast

Comment: @Kiwy ya i m trying hard to grep some words from it but not getting exactly how to use that i just want to grep ip , accepted,or failed,user name.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks for suggestion i am trying it out